# linkedlist with class in the struct can't get bool operation working

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, boolean

I can't seem to get `Boolean` operation working like I thought it works.

```
/////.h file

class linkD
{

  private:
struct ListNode{
    driver driver;   ////class 
    ListNode *next;
};
ListNode *head;

///.cpp file

  void linkD::deleteNode(driver d){

ListNode *nodePtr;
ListNode *previousNode;
ListNode *newNode;
newNode=new ListNode;
newNode->next=NULL;
newNode->driver=d;

if(!head)
    return;
if(head->driver==d) //the problem is right here.
{
    nodePtr=head->next;
    delete head;
    head=nodePtr;
}
```

`head->driver==d` gives a redline (**no operator "==" matches these operands**)

I think it is because `head->driver` is uninitialized but I might be wrong and I am not sure how to initialize it since it's inside a uninitialized struct.

Comment: Advice: Never name your variables after their type: `driver driver; // BAD` Also, what exactly is that `driver` class?

Comment: no its inside a struct, how would i do initialize it??

Comment: @ xeo haha i know, it driver was already created from another project so i didnt want to do back and rename everything. if this was a brand new project i wouldnt have done that

Comment: Is the == operator overloaded for the driver type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because driver is a class object.

You have to define the equality operator for a class.

Are you expecting class object to be pointer like (as in Java i.e. They can be NULL)

If you want to test driver objects for equality define it like this:

```
class driver
{
    public:
        bool operator==(driver const& rhs) const
        {
            return  x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y && z == rhs.z;
        }
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
};

int test
{
     driver x;
     driver y;

     if (x == y)   // this calls x.operator==(y)
     {             // So y is the rhs parameter.
     }
}
```

Comment: so i need to go into the driver.h/.cpp and overload/define the "==" operator? if so how would i set it to do a normal "=="

Comment: wow thanks that did the job! so just for knowledge, i have to define all the Boolean for the class if i want to use it?? also, what is "rhs"?? is that just a random var?

Comment: The question is how do you know if two driver objects are the same? Updated answer to show where rhs comes from.

Comment: @martin york no, it was why did the compiler complained, it was because i needed to define the operator.

Comment: it fixed the complaining, but its giving an error on compile that the function needs to return a value. how do i get it to do the default operation?? do i have to test all the member of the class with the rhs?? and return true or false??

Comment: @kingcong3: That is the simplest way. But it depnds on how you define equality for the type. On complex classes the logic can be completely different. i.e. On some types each object is an individual and even if there individual members are equal does not make them the same (in this case you can test their address is the same if the address is the same then its the same object).

Comment: aight cool, thanks a lot Martin i'll tinker with it for a while. how do i give rep??

Answer (score 1):

The `class/struct driver` in your code doesn't seem to have defined the `operator ==()` and because of that the compiler is complaining.